# reactjs remove spellcheck attribute

Tags: reactjs

I'm using ReactJS to render my DOM.

I want to add the `spellcheck="false"` attribute on a text input, so I do this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>   
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" spellcheck="false" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then, when I inspect with chrome, the `spellcheck` attribute is not present.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using `spellCheck` instead. (Note the capital C)

[The docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#html-attributes) are good for explaining how default HTML attributes should be referenced in React.