# React Typescript: Disable spellcheck

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have tried to disable spell check but typescript isn't happy

```
<form>
   <input
      type='text'
      name='accountName'
      ref={accountName}
      onChange={checkName}
      spellCheck='false' // <====== Disable spellcheck here
   />
</form>
```

The error I got is...

```
Type '{ type: string; name: string; ref: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>; onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<Element>) => Promise<void>; spellcheck: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'spellcheck' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reactjs remove spellcheck attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079148/reactjs-remove-spellcheck-attribute)

Comment: Unfortunately I get a slightly different error from typescript `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1658, 9): The expected type comes from property 'spellCheck' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'
`

Comment: It should be `spellCheck={false}`

Comment: That got it! Thank you

Comment: But that doesn't match the spec, which is an enumerated value.  And in HTML spellcheck="false" is different from the absence of the attribute.  Is React accounting for this, and if so how?  Maybe they're doing an explicit check to determine between `false` and `undefined`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck

Answer (score 2):

Try `spellCheck` (capitalized `C`). Remember that React attributes are camel-cased!

The React docs have a list of all attributes and their correct names [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes).

[EDIT] In light of the new edit to the question, make sure you're passing a boolean `{false}`, not a string `{"false"}` or `"false"`.

Comment: I tried this but I get a slightly different error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1658, 9): The expected type comes from property 'spellCheck' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'
`

Comment: @Bill use spellcheck={false}